# React Redux Auth Middlware

Tags: reactjs, redux, middleware

I am doing a login application using react/redux, here is my flow.

- User logs in using email/password pair and receives a token, which I
  store in the cookie.
- Once I have the token, I can get his credentials by doing a request on an `/auth` endpoint which retrieves his personal details - firstname, lastname, email.

I have a PrivateRoute which used to do the auth check, however I want to trigger the auth check on all routes, not only the private ones.
This way if the user is viewing the homepage I can still show his firstname in the navigation (for example)
The main issue seems to be the proper place to call the auth action.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

// Styling
import './App.css';

// Privat route
import PrivateRoute from './routes/PrivateRoute';

// Common
import Navigation from './components/common/Navigation';

// Components
import Login from './components/Login';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Profile from './components/Profile';
import ArticlesList from './components/Profile/ArticlesList';
import ArticleForm from './components/Profile/ArticleForm';

const App = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                {/* Public routes */}
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />

                {/* Private routes */}
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/profile/articles" component={ArticlesList} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/profile/articles/new" component={ArticleForm} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/profile/articles/:id(\d+)" component={ArticleForm} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </Provider> 
);

export default App;
```

Here is a piece of my **userActions.js** where the auth action is defined

```
export const auth = () => async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER_REQUEST });

    try{
        let data = await UserService.auth();

        dispatch({
            type: AUTH_USER_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        });
    }catch(err){
        dispatch({
            type: AUTH_USER_ERROR,
            payload: err.message
        });
    }
}
```

One of my ideas was to create a parent Route class to do the routing, and call the `auth` there.

Answer (score 0):

To overcome it, I did something like the following by using Redux:

```
<Switch>
  <Route 
    path="/"
    component={this.props.auth.authenticationInProgress ? BlankPage : 
      (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated ? SegmentPage : LoginPage)}
    exact={true}
  />
  <Route component={NotFoundPage}/>
</Switch>
```

If the user logged in, the Route renders SegmentPage. Otherwise it renders LoginPage. Once login or logout process is triggered, the authentication is toggled and the page renders accordingly. Also I keep the status of authentication process so that no private data is shown to the user during the authentication check.

Comment: I have to call the auth middleware from all routes, including ones that are not protected.